# How to check timeout for a existing Zookeeper Ephemeral Node?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I know that Zookeeper Server has  a config named "tickTime" (minimum heartbeat time =2*ticktime) and clients can request for a "session timeout".

When a connection is established.. it gets a  session time out associated with it. This is negotiated between client and server.

How to find what value they both settled on?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the ZooKeeper instance has a method for it: getSessionTimeout(). The comment for it is:

```
public int getSessionTimeout()

The negotiated session timeout for this ZooKeeper client instance. 
The value returned is not valid until the client connects to a server 
and may change after a re-connect. This method is NOT thread safe

Returns:
current session timeout
```